# Sorting a month array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I am currently working with a rather difficult sorting problem.

I have an array indicating months. Lets assume the array looks like this:

```
mth = [3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;1;2;3;4;5;6]
```

I want to sort the above mentioned such that:

```
mth = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12]
```

and the rest should appear in another array:

```
mthDiscard =[3;4;5;6]
```

Now suppose that we exceed 2 years, then I want the sorting to look like this:

```
mth = [3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;1;2;3;4;5;6]
```

such that:

```
mth = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12]
mthDiscard = [3;4;5;6]
```

How would I be able to achieve this sorting?

**More info:**

I need to mentioned that I for each month have a vector with consumption values. I want to achieve it sucht that I get the consumption values for each month spread over periodically years only! Hence if I have 13 months of data I will discard one month.

Comment: Is your data always cyclically sorted already, as in your examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to look at the number of times each month is present. There will be only one or two such values, say `m` and possibly `m+1`. Months that appear more than `m` times, if any, are discarded. The final result is `1:12` repeated `m` times.

```
n = histc(mth,1:12); %// number of times each month is present
m = min(n);
mthDiscard = find(n>m); %// these are discarded as they don't fill a whole year
mth = repmat(1:12,1,m).'; %'// final result
```

Comment: On second thought, this answer is quite general: there is no need for `mth` to be cyclically sorted. Edited

Comment: I ended up using your method and rather well working I must admit.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your criteria for "discarding" months, I think you are simply taking the longest sequence of 12*k month, as in:

```
idx = fix(numel(mth)/12)*12;
mth_kept = mth(1:idx)
mth_discarded = mth(idx+1:end)
```

Then if you want the sequence to always start at 1, we can perform circular shifting:

```
circshift(mth_kept, mth(1)-1)
```

(assuming the months are always sorted in order, and that there are no missing months in between).